# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2}$ without n dots to $\mathbb{R^2}$ without n other dots

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I need to prove that if we take off from $\mathbb{R^2}$ n dots,it doesnt matter which dots we take off from this space,meaning:

Let $n$ be a natural  number,and let $K,K'$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that that $K=${$p_1$,...,$p_n$},and $K'=${$p'_1$,...,$p'_n$}.

Prove that $\mathbb{R^2}$\K is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$\K'.

So I thought about the following functions:

f: $\mathbb{R^2}$\K->$\mathbb{R^2}$\K'

Defined as:

f(p)=p if p isn't in $K'$.,and $p_i$ if it is in $K'$.
(meaning that if p is in $K'$,with index i,so its image will be the $i$-th in $K$ set).

g will be the same just the opposite.

So the composition of f and g is the ID function,But I'm not sure how to prove that these functions are continuous(if at all).

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is unclear. $f(p)=p$ if $p \notin K'$; if $p \in K'$, then $p=p_i'$ for some index $i$, and $f(p_i')=p_i$? 

This is not even a map from $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus K'$ if $K \neq K'$. For one, you are defining $f$ at $p_1',\dots,p_n'$, which are not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K$, and you have $p_1,\dots,p_n$ in the image of $f$, but the points are not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus K'$.

Comment: @kccu What i meant is,that if we look at some order of $K$ and $K'$,(maybe by  x?),then if $p$ is the $i$-th in $K'$ in this order,its image $f(p)$ will be the $i$-th number in the order in $K$.

Comment: @WakaWaka123 The functions you defined are not continuous in general.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Ok,so can you help me/give me a hint for functions that will suffice?

Comment: @WakaWaka123 So your definition is exactly what I wrote. But it doesn't make sense to write $f(p_1')=p_1$, because $p_1$ might not be in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus K'$.

Comment: @kccu So can you help me find other functions?

Comment: The function must certainly not continuous as it's simply "ripping" and replacing the bad points.  Intuitively we want a function where the "bad" points of one set map continuously to the bad points of the other and all the other points get nudged along for the ride.  Or to put it differently let f:R^2->R^2 be a homeomorphism where for each p_i in K, f(p_i) = q_i in K'.  It's easy to argue that such a map will when restricted to R^2\K will be a homeomorphism to R^2\K'.  What may be harder is arguing such a mapping exists.

Comment: @WakaWaka123 There is already an answer to your question which I don't think I can improve upon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The case-wise definition should have immediately raised suspicion: $f$ is not continouous at points of $K'\setminus K$. As a matter of fact. it may not even be a map $\Bbb R^2\setminus K\to\Bbb R\setminus K'$.

**Lemma 1.** Let $\Bbb H=\Bbb R\times(0,\infty)$,  $\overline{\Bbb H}=\Bbb R\times [0,\infty)$, $a,b\in\Bbb H$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $\overline {\Bbb H}\setminus\{a\}\to \overline{\Bbb H}\setminus\{b\}$ that is the identity on $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$.

*Proof.* Try $(x,y)\mapsto (x+\alpha y,\beta y)$ for suitable $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$. $\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $\Bbb I=\Bbb R\times(0,1)$,  $\overline{\Bbb I}=\Bbb R\times [0,1]$, $a,b\in\Bbb I$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $\overline {\Bbb I}\setminus\{a\}\to \overline{\Bbb I}\setminus\{b\}$ that is the identity on $\Bbb R\times \{0,1\}$.

*Proof.* Try $(x,y)\mapsto (x+\alpha y(1-y),y+\beta y(1-y))$ for suitable $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$. $\square$

Now for the problem at hand, we may assume wlog. (namely, by applying a rotation if necessary) that the points in $K$ have pairwise different $y$-coordinates.
Then we can split $\Bbb R^2\setminus K$ by horizontal lines into parts that are $\approx \Bbb H\setminus \{a\}$ or $\approx \Bbb I\setminus\{a\}$ via homeomorphisms of the form $(x,y)\mapsto (x,\alpha +\beta y)$. We can do the same for $\Bbb R^2\setminus K'$. Then for these parts in top to bottom order apply lemma 1 and 2. Verify that these homeomorphisms glue nicely to a homeomorphism $\Bbb  R^2\setminus K\to \Bbb r^2\setminus K'$.

Comment: Nice. I was having in mind to proceed by induction using a transformation like the one of your **Lemma 1** for the induction step.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen A few things that I don't understand- Why do we need the second lemma?And the seoncd thing is after we split the space into horiznotal lines,so each line is honenorphic to one of those space from the lemma,but why doe sit mean that when you add all those lines together back to the original space its still homeomorphic?

Comment: You can get away with only lemma 1 by dividing the plane into wedges instead. Pick a point that is not collinear with any two points of $K$, and draw rays from that point like spokes in a wheel, each section containing a single point of $K$.

Comment: @WakaWaka123 Both lemmas leave the boundary lines fixed. Therefore you can "glue" the individual homeomorphisms. I deliberately did not want to spell out all the details though. Note that the final map is of the form $(x,y)mapsto (x+f(y),g(y))$, where $f,g$ are defined piecewise.

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, using that the wedge is homeomorphic to the half plane. More precisely one would use a lemma that any two closed wedges with one missing interior point are homeomorphic via a homeomorphism that identifies the apex points and is an isometry on each of the bounding rays (so that the glueing works out)